# Translate color to hexadecimal c#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, hex

I have problem with conversion color to hexadecimal. Red underline is below `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("paint")` and `rect.Color;`
Variable `paint` is static - for now.

In my opinion the problem is in variable's type public `System.Drawing.SolidBrush Color` at `Rect` class

```
 List<Rect> rects = new List<Rect>();
        rects.Add(new Rect()
        {
            Width = x,
            Height = y,
            Left = w,
            Top = h,
            Fill = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)(new BrushConverter()).ConvertFromString(paint)
        });

        foreach (Rect rect in rects)
        {
             Rectangle r = new Rectangle
             {
                 Width = rect.Width,
                 Height = rect.Width,
                 Fill = rect.Fill
             };
             Canvas.SetLeft(r, rect.Left);
            Canvas.SetTop(r, rect.Top);


            canvas.Children.Add(r);

        }


    }

class Rect
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
     public System.Windows.Media.Brush Fill { get; set; }
}


private void rectangle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    choose r1 = new choose();
    var paint = "#FFA669D1";

    int x = int.Parse(beginx.Text);
    int y = int.Parse(beginy.Text);
    int w = int.Parse(wid.Text);
    int h = int.Parse(hei.Text);

    if (!((x > canvas.ActualWidth) || (y > canvas.ActualHeight) || (w > canvas.ActualWidth) || (h > canvas.ActualHeight)))
    {
        r1.rectangle(x, y, w, h, paint, canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all get rid of the quotes around "paint" : `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(paint)`

Comment: What kind of variable in "paint"?

Comment: paint is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the incompatible WinForms type `System.Drawing.SolidBrush` for the `Fill` property of a WPF Rectangle. Use `System.Windows.Media.Brush` instead:

```
class Rect
{
    ...
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the WPF `BrushConverter` class to convert a hexadecimal color string to a Brush:

```
rect.Fill = (Brush)(new BrushConverter()).ConvertFromString(paint);
```

---

In your code sample, it should look like this:

```
var converter = new BrushConverter();

rects.Add(new Rect
{
    Width = x,
    Height = y,
    Left = w,
    Top = h,
    Fill = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(paint)
});

foreach (Rect rect in rects)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle
    {
        Width = rect.Width,
        Height = rect.Width,
        Fill = rect.Fill
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(r, rect.Left);
    Canvas.SetTop(r, rect.Top);
    canvas.Children.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did what you write.I don't have any errors but still nothing happens.
The variable paint is var and I deleted **Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("paint")**

Comment: You mean the Rectangle doesn't get its Fill property set?

Comment: I think, I put instead paint  #FFA669D1, but still nothing.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you're actually doing now. Anyway, see my edit.

Comment: Now, I have red underline below **r** and **Fill** = rect.Fill.
The error says that " Cannot convert System.Drawing.Rectangle  to System.Windows.UIElement" - to the variable **r** and " Element Rectangle has no definition  Fill" - to the position Fill. 
I update my code.

Comment: Remove all `using System.Drawing...` lines from your code and use the correct WPF namespaces, e.g. `using System.Windows.Shapes;`